# VS Code is not reopening the last open file editors after crashing

Tags: visual-studio-code

The opened files on my VS Code are all enqueued for a review before I close them one by one. The problem is whenever my VS Code crash, it is NOT restoring my last *"enqueued to review"* opened files, instead it is restoring the opened files on its startup. The last opened file reopening after I close my VS Code without any crash is working as expected.

Is there any solution or configuration, that will make my VS Code restores the last opened saved files after crashing?

#### My User Settings:

- "Files: Hot Exit" is set to `onExitAndWindowClose`.

  > Controls whether unsaved files are remembered between sessions, allowing the save prompt when exiting the editor to be skipped.
- "Window: Restore Windows" is set to `one`. **Will setting it to `all` makes difference?**

  > Controls how windows are being reopened after a restart.